# Extract all text after two not necessarily consecutive words

Tags: regex

I have a string like

```
deleted - the status was being deleted and got it back with it.
```

on which I want to use a regex. Here the fixed elements are the words `status` and `deleted`. In-between them can be different text, and I need to ignore that.

Now my regex is `(?<=status).*`

This takes all after 'status', but I need to ignore everything from 'status' to 'deleted' and take rest of it.

E.g. input:

```
deleted - the status was being deleted and got it back with it.
```

Desired output:

```
and got it back with it.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please clarify what you're doing and what your question is.  Your post isn't clear as to what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: It is quite clear that you need `status.*?deleted\s+(.*)` or one of its variations. `(?<=status.*?deleted\s+).*` might [work](https://regex101.com/r/tJNs7V/1) for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
status.*?deleted\s+(.*)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tJNs7V/2). You need to access Group 1 value to get the necessary result.

Or, if you have an infinite-width lookbehind pattern support in your environment, use

```cs
(?<=status.*?deleted\s+).*
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tJNs7V/1).

**NOTE**: If the whitespaces after `deleted` are optional, use `\s*` instead of `\s+`.

**Details**

- `(?<=` -  start of a positive lookbehind that matches a location in string that is immediately preceded with its pattern:
- `status.*?deleted` - `status`, then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible, and then `deleted`
- `\s+` - one or more whitespace chars
- `)` - end of the lookbehind
- `.*` - zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
/(?P<status>[a-z]+) -.+(?P=status) (.*)/
```

See:
https://regex101.com/r/pKnaAc/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use a positive lookbehind, just as you are doing now, but you need to add all your requirements (additional text and the delimiter `deleted`):

```
(?<=status.*deleted).*
```

Should get you what you want.